# configure.ac permission denied

Tags: 13.04, permissions

```
haxxm32@haxxm32-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ '/home/haxxm32/sm-ssc/configure.ac' 
bash: /home/haxxm32/sm-ssc/configure.ac: Permission denied
```

What do I do about this?  I tried to run this:

```
haxxm32@haxxm32-HP-EliteBook-6930p:~$ '/home/haxxm32/sm-ssc/autogen.sh' 
aclocal-1.11: `configure.ac' or `configure.in' is required
autoconf: error: no input file
autoheader: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
automake-1.11: `configure.ac' or `configure.in' is required
```

but as it said, this doesn't run due to denied permissions. Please help?

Comment: Tried `chmod u+x /home/haxxm32/sm-ssc/configure.ac` before running it?

Comment: also, why the need of the quotes? I believe that your sources are dirty, download the file again and start again.

Answer (score 1):

Usually `configure.ac` isn't some you should run but an input file for `autogen.sh`.

`autogen.sh` is looking for `configure.ac` or `configure.in` in the current working folder. Most likely one of them is in `/home/haxxm32/sm-ssc` so you need to go there before you run `autogen.sh`:

```
cd /home/haxxm32/sm-ssc
./autogen.sh
```